# Closet partial wall removal

Tags: drywall, walls, removal

Removing a partial wall in my bedroom, this room is against the side of the house and the wall is perpendicular to my houses Joists but isn't anywhere near the center of my home.

The partial wall use to hold large mirror closet sliding doors, planning on removing the wall. I noticed however while tearing the drywall, that the inside edge contains two 2x4's along with some metal mesh around the outside edge.

My question is, is there any reason not to remove this wall? I'm pretty new to all of this and I'm missing the correct terms to discover what exactly is happening here and why the metal mesh exist, etc.

Thanks

[image: Partial closest wall opened]

[image: Partial closest wall]

[image: Double 2x4 with some metal sheet along the outside.]

Comment: I don't see any "metal mesh" in any of these photos.

Comment: Is the metal mesh on the corner of the drywall?  If there is nothing heavy above this wall(hot tub/10 ton safe) or supports beneath, then it is probably safe to remove.  What is the rod like thing in the bottom picture?

Comment: Doubled studs are standard for supporting a header above a doorway. Is the opening through which you walk full height to the ceiling or is this a "doorway" but without a door?

Comment: The mesh is being pinned with the nail, seems to be holding drywall on I believe. The opening you can walk through full height, I would say this is a "doorway" without a door.

Comment: @ben I would agree that looks like metal corner for the drywall, and a very possible support for a header above , a photo from further back would be helpful.

Comment: I believe this to be a corner bead after some searching, not seeing any reason not to more the wall since it can't be load bearing be that it's attached to an exterior wall, and the metal mesh appears to be a corner bead to keep the corners of walls sharp.